# Updating a column on all rows in a table with an incrementing integer

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
name | order
------------
foo    0
bar    0
john   0
doe    0
```

I'd like to create a SQL update that will order these by the name column, such as:

```
name | order
------------
foo    2
bar    0
john   3
doe    1
```

This is for SQL Server.

I've seen that something like this works for inserting, but not for updating obviously.

```
insert into [dbo].[MyTable](Order)
  select row_number() over (order by Name)
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select 
    name
  , row_number() over (order by name)-1 as [order]
from t
```

For an update: using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      name
    , [order]
    , row_number() over (order by name)-1 as [NewOrder]
  from t
)
update cte
  set [order] = NewOrder;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VSF47884

returns:

```
+------+-------+
| name | order |
+------+-------+
| foo  |     2 |
| bar  |     0 |
| john |     3 |
| doe  |     1 |
+------+-------+
```

---

You could skip the common table expression and just use a subquery, but I think it is easier to read using the cte.

```
update s
  set [order] = NewOrder
from (
  select 
      name
    , [order]
    , row_number() over (order by name)-1 as [NewOrder]
  from t
  ) as s
```

Comment: Impressive Ranking as of late.  Way to be Value-Added

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Very punny :D

Comment: Seriously, You're 23 shy of Gordon.  However, I have a concern if he lost his #1 rank, it would signal the end of days.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti It's just early in the month, I'm sure it won't last. Thanks for noticing though ^.^